# Google maps universal URL error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

Using the [Google Maps universal cross-platform URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action), I want maps to point to a specified location.

> The search action displays results for a search across the visible map region. When searching for a specific place, the resulting map puts a pin in the specified location and displays available place details.

Using maps web interface, I pick a point on map, for instance with coordinates [49.258786662320986,-123.0241870880127]. These are valid coordinates which will point map to existing location when searched from Google maps web interface:

[image]

The same coordinates in the query

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search?api=1&query=49.258786662320986,-123.0241870880127
```

will result in error 404.

Why valid geo coordinates from Google web interface not working in Google Universal URL API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just noticed that in the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action) the URL is

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&parameters`

Note a `/` symbol after `/search` and before `?api=1`. Once I added this missing `/` in your sample URL, the 404 disappeared

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=49.258786662320986,-123.0241870880127`

Not sure if this behavior is intentional though.